# Determine precision of average estimated with MCMC

Tags: confidence-interval, markov-chain-montecarlo, expected-value, metropolis-hastings

I am using a Markov chain Monte Carlo method (Metropolis-Hastings) to estimate the mean of a distribution.

What practical methods can be used to efficiently determine the precision of this estimate, especially when the acceptance rate drops?

Specifically, is there a better way than to recompute the average several times and look at the spread of the results?

The keyword here is *efficiency*: I'm hoping to find a way to calculate the average relatively precisely and estimate that precision without increasing the computation time.  The long computation time is a problem in my application.  It will not be possible to calculate the average precisely in all cases (when the acceptance rate drops), and it's especially important to have an estimate of the precision when this happens.

Comment: I saw [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/finding-precision-of-monte-carlo-simulation-estimate) already.  It doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate a posterior [Credible Interval](http://www.stat.sc.edu/~hitchcock/stat535slidesday3.pdf) about your estimate. These are usually calculated from quantiles or using the "Highest Posterior Density (HPD)" region. This is slightly different from the "precision" of the estimate, but I believe you are thinking of this from a frequentist perspective and are sort of missing the forest for the trees. The credible interval is the Bayesian analog to the confidence interval, and I believe it is the quantity you should be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

One answer lies in [this article](http://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Article.pdf), specifically, Eq. (17), (18) and section D where a method is proposed to compute $\tau_A$ in Eq. (18).